# Animation of Bitmaps in SDCard and without XML?

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, android-animation, android-drawable

Let's suppose your program generates N bitmaps at runtime ad stores them in your emulator's sdcard, and you want create a sort of video, replacing them in fast succession.

`imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` inside a `for` doesn't work because it only shows the last bitmap, so i should use an animation, right?

Tutorials say i should create a XML like this one:

```
 <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />
 </animation-list>
```

BUT resources (bitmaps) are not inside my drawable folder, so i can't create this XML in advance. I have to do everything programmatically, am I correct?

This is what i'm trying to do, but it obviously crashes:

```
 public class ReplayVideo extends ActionBarActivity {

private ImageView replayView;
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) replayView.getBackground();  // Program crashes here!        

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_replay_video);
    replayView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.replay);
    new replayAsync().execute();
}
```

And inside my replayAsync task, in doInBackground method i have this:

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for ( int c = 0; c < 10; c++){

                    String path = temp + File.separator + c + ".jpg";   //c is the filename!

                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                    frameAnimation.addFrame(Drawable.createFromPath(path), 200);

                }
                frameAnimation.start();                 
            }

        });
```

But everything crashes, probably because i have to set a background right?

Tutorials say i should use

```
replayView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
```

But i can't create this if i don't have any item to insert at compile time, so that animation-list in animation xml will be empty...

What can i do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the log cat for when your program crashed? It will probably be complaining that replayView is null, as you are trying to get the background before you initialize it 3 lines down.

Also when you did the just the for loop, was there a delay?

And lastly, animation drawable is probably not the best choice for this. Depending on your image size and how many images you have, you can run into out of memory errors. It is also not the fastest method either. I recommend using a canvas or even better a texture view, or even looking into opengl solutions.